# Eagerly Loaded Associations on sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following entities:

```
var Group = sequelize.define("Group", { name: Sequelize.STRING });
var Course = sequelize.define("Course", { name: Sequelize.STRING });
var GroupHasCourse = sequelize.define("GroupHasCourse", { name: Sequelize.STRING });
var Student = sequelize.define("Group", {   name: Sequelize.STRING });
```

And the following associations:

```
Course.hasMany(GroupHasCourse, { as: "GroupsOnCourses"});
Group.hasMany(GroupHasCourse, { as: "CoursesOnGroups"});
GroupHasCourse.hasMany(Student, { as: "Students"});
```

Two questions:

1. Is this the best way to do the association between the Group-Course relationship in order to get students into the subjets?
2. I'm doing the following query:

   ```
   Course.findAll({include:[{model:GroupHasCourse, as:"GroupsOnCourses"}]}).success(function(courses){
       // courses[0].groupsOnCourses[0].GroupId
   })
   ```

   How can I get also the left join in that query so I dont need to do another query having

   ```
   Group.find(courses[0].groupsOnCourses[0].GroupId)
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this already works with 1.6.0:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize')
var sequelize = new Sequelize('sequelize_test', 'root')

var Group = sequelize.define("Group", { name: Sequelize.STRING })
var Course = sequelize.define("Course", { name: Sequelize.STRING })
var GroupHasCourse = sequelize.define("GroupHasCourse", { name: Sequelize.STRING })
var Student = sequelize.define("Group", {   name: Sequelize.STRING })

Course.hasMany(GroupHasCourse, { as: "GroupsOnCourses"})
Group.hasMany(GroupHasCourse, { as: "CoursesOnGroups"})
GroupHasCourse.hasMany(Student, { as: "Students"}).belongsTo(Group).belongsTo(Course)

sequelize.sync({ force: true }).success(function() {
  Group.create({ name: 'group' }).success(function(group) {
    Course.create({ name: 'course' }).success(function(course) {
      GroupHasCourse.create({ name: 'bla' }).success(function(groupHasCourse) {
        groupHasCourse.setGroup(group).success(function() {
          groupHasCourse.setCourse(course).success(function() {
            GroupHasCourse.findAll({
              include: [ Group, Course ]
            }).success(function(groupHasCourses) {
              console.log(groupHasCourses[0].values)
            })
          })
        })
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: yes, that works, actually I have the same code, but what I need is to have the query from the Groups and get in some way the info about Courses trough GroupHasCourses

Answer (score 2):

do you need the join table for further data or are you just connecting Corse and Group? If you just want to connect them you can do this:

```
Course.hasMany(Group)
Group.hasMany(Course)
```

This will create the join table for you automagically. If you want that way, your next will be, that you wait for a first alpha/beta/whatever of Sequelize 1.6.1 which will support eager loading for many-to-many associations. The version will be available during the week.

Greetings,
sdepold

Comment: The join table is needed so the students can have many-to-many association to the many-to-many association between Course and Group. Guess I'll wait for it then :)

Comment: Has this been implemented yet? (eager joins using associative table)